"Lifetimes do not match" when implementing object_store trait that returns a BoxStream
I am trying to implement the object_store trait of arrow-rs for webhdfs.
When trying to implement the "list" function I am getting the error:
lifetime parameters or bounds on method `list` do not match the trait declaration
 148 |     async fn list(self, prefix: Option<&Path>) -> BoxStream<'_, Result<ObjectMeta>> {
        |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetimes do not match method in trait

The implementation looks like:
#[async_trait]
impl ObjectStore for HDLStore {

async fn list(self, prefix: Option<&Path>) -> BoxStream<'_, Result<ObjectMeta>> {

        let pf = match prefix {
            None => "/".to_string(),
            Some(p) => p.to_string(),
        };

        match self.client.list_recursive(&pf).await {
            Err(e) =>  Box::pin(futures::stream::once(async move{Err(Error::Generic{store: "HDLFS get",source:Box::new(e)})})),
            Ok(fs) => {
                    let objmeta: Vec<ObjectMeta> = fs.list.into_iter().map(|f| from_filecontent(f)).collect();
                    let stream = objmeta.into_iter().map(Ok);
                    Box::pin(futures::stream::iter(stream))
                },
        }
    }

The call self.client.list_recursive(&pf) is a reqwest-API-call that returns a struct that contains a vector.
I cannot add lifetimes to the trait and all my trials to tackle this error failed.

list() is not async and cannot be async.

It also takes &self not self.

Many thanks. Indeed the trait is without a async and the & has been accidentally deleted with the added lifetime. Super thanks
